# Modal pop up repeating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">More Details</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Per Serve : 5g   Energy : 20kcal Protein : 0.0g Fat­Total : 0.0g  Saturated &nbsp; 0.0g  Carbohydrate : 0.0g Package Size : 1 x 24 x 350 g</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
     </div>
  </div>

<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Quick inquiry</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is the one that wont work(Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Another data that wont appear</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Outer */
.popup {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
  max-width:700px;
  width:90%;
  padding:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  padding-top:4px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  transition:ease 0.25s all;
  -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(50%, -50%);
  border-radius:1000px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100%;
  color:#fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
//----- OPEN
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

The code works but it doesn't show the second pop up's content. I have tried different jquery pop up as well but nothing changes the data inside the pop up. When the next button is clicked, the data in the box remains the same. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `data-popup` attributes for each popup, e.g. `popup-1` for the first and `popup-2` for the second:

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">More Details</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Per Serve : 5g   Energy : 20kcal Protein : 0.0g Fat­Total : 0.0g  Saturated &nbsp; 0.0g  Carbohydrate : 0.0g Package Size : 1 x 24 x 350 g</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
     </div>
  </div>

<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">Quick inquiry</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is the one that wont work(Popup #2)</h2>
    <p>Another data that wont appear</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `data-popup-open` value on the second `<a>` element and change the `data-popup` on the second `<div class="popup">` element to match. This is under the assumption your javascript and css work.

```html
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">More Details</a>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
  <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Per Serve : 5g Energy : 20kcal Protein : 0.0g Fat­Total : 0.0g Saturated &nbsp; 0.0g Carbohydrate : 0.0g Package Size : 1 x 24 x 350 g</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
    </p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Changed data-popup-open to popup-2 -->
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">Quick inquiry</a>
<!-- Change data-popup to popup-2 -->
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
  <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is the one that wont work(Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Another data that wont appear</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
    </p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `data-popup-open` and `data-popup` in the second modal

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">More Details</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Per Serve : 5g   Energy : 20kcal Protein : 0.0g Fat­Total : 0.0g  Saturated &nbsp; 0.0g  Carbohydrate : 0.0g Package Size : 1 x 24 x 350 g</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
     </div>
  </div>

<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">Quick inquiry</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is the one that wont work(Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Another data that wont appear</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/873ww7pj/

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet its Working.. for more modals change id or popup name

```js
$(function() {
//----- OPEN
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```css
/* Outer */
.popup {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* Inner */
 .popup-inner {
max-width:700px;
width:90%;
padding:40px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-radius:3px;
background:#fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
width:30px;
height:30px;
padding-top:4px;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
transition:ease 0.25s all;
-webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
transform:translate(50%, -50%);
border-radius:1000px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
line-height:100%;
color:#fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
-webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">More Details</a>

  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>Wow! This is Awesome! (Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Per Serve : 5g   Energy : 20kcal Protein : 0.0g Fat­Total : 0.0g  Saturated &nbsp; 0.0g  Carbohydrate : 0.0g Package Size : 1 x 24 x 350 g</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
     </div>
  </div>

<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">Quick inquiry</a>
  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
    <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is the one that wont work(Popup #1)</h2>
    <p>Another data that wont appear</p>
    <p><a data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">Close</a></p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```